# Javascript regex phone validation

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone suggest a js function to validate a phone number which has to start with **0** and be followed by any other digit? I am not concerned about the size, because I have maxlength="10" in my html code. I now use a simple js function in order to restrict letters and other symbols from the phone nr. Any help is welcome!

Comment: So, 012 would be a valid number? `maxlength` isn't `exactlength`!

Comment: if you want some form validation, you'd probably do it client side (i'll remove your other tags). Some jquery plugins will do the job very well: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the .match function of string variables.
eg.

```
var myString = $("#myPhoneNumebrField").val();
if (myString.match(/0[0-9]+/))
{
  //Valid stuff here
}
else
{
  //Invalid stuff here
}
```

As suggested by others, you probably want a minimum size in which case you can change the regex to be `/0[0-9]{8,10}/` which will make the regex only match if the string is between 8 and 10 characters long (Inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

This regex should do: `/^0[0-9]+$/`

But you should also implement a **minimum size**.

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need a regex for this, instead write a function which iterates over the string.
2. Try to do it yourself, you can start with [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions). You will learn much more if you do not quote a ready made solution from SOF.